# Compiler incorrectly interpretes as recursive call

Tags: scala

Compiler complain that method defined in class A is a recursive one and needs result.type but it's not recursive as I'm calling different method, it's a compiler bug ?

> def my(s:String)  {
>
> }
>
> class A {
>        def my = my("sss")   }

Comment: Personally, I'd just add an explicit result type and move on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can't have methods outside of classes/traits/objects, I guess that `A` is an inner class. If so, you can do it as follows:

```
class Foo { outer =>
  def my(s:String) {

  }

  class A { def my = outer.my("sss") }

}
```

The notation `outer =>` is called a self-type annotation and is used in this form simply to create an alias for the `this` of `class Foo` that is not shadowed by the `this` of the nested type.

**edit**:

If the outer entity is an `object`, you can just reference it by its name.

**edit2**:

If you have overloaded methods it is a different error. If you call an overloaded method from within one of the alternatives, it needs a result type.

```
def my(s: String) = s
def my: String = my("foo")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

my: (s: String)String <and> => String
my: (s: String)String <and> => String

scala> my
res0: String = foo
```

Comment: Your justification is not correct, it is not that methods are shadowed, they can be defined in very same name space and you will have same behaviour, it all about the way the scala treats overloaded methods, compiler can not differentiate between them and I do not know why ?

Comment: Edited my post to answer the case with overloaded methods.

Comment: Also... in the first case, where you have an inner class, it has nothing to do with overloading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your def a different name, for example:

```
class A { def my2 = my("sss") }
```

Comment: what if he can't change the names?

Comment: Yes I know that,what I do not know is why it behaving like this